# Recursive function with array in C

Tags: c, recursion

The problem goes as follows:

- Write a recursive function with three arguments: an array (a), the
  number of elements of the array (n) and a number - k.
- If k is positive and smaller than n it should print the first k positive
  numbers of the array.
- If k is negative and its absolute value is smaller than n the first k negative numbers should be printed.
- If k is larger than n and positive all positive numbers should be printed.
- If k is larger than n and negative all negative numbers should be
  printed.

This is my attempt

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int function(int a[100], int n, int k)
    {
      int b[n], i;

      if (k!=0 && n>1)
      {
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
          b[i]=a[i+1];
        }

        if (k<n || abs(k)<n)
        {

         if (k>0)
          {
            if (b[0]>0)
            {
              printf("%d", b[0]);
              k=k-1;
            }
          }

          if (k<0)
          {
            if (b[0]<0)
            {
              printf("%d", b[0]);
              k=k+1;
            }
          }
          return function(b, n-1, k);
        }
      }

      else return 0;
    }

   int main() 
   {
     int i, n, a[100], k;
     printf("n = ");
     scanf("%d", &n);
     for (i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
       printf("a[%d] = ", i);
       scanf("%d", &a[i]);
     }
     printf("k = ");
     scanf("%d", &k);
     printf("The new array is: \n");
     function(a, n, k);
     return 0;
   }
```

But it only prints one number and I don't know how to fix it. Does anyone understand where I went wrong?

EDIT: If the array is {1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3} and k=2, the expected result is {1, 2}. If k=-2 the expected result is {-1, -2}

EDIT 2: b is an array that contains all the elements of the a array other than a[0]

Comment: Now is a good time to lean how to use a debugger.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing the sample data you used to test your code, and the *specific* output you expected from that data, *and* the output you actually received. The simpler the better. [Edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48812945/edit) to address these missing elements.

Comment: If you see in the description the *and* word, why are you translating it into `||` operator? BTW, `abs(k) = -k` in case of negative `k`.

Comment: Why are you creating a new array `b` each time? Especially as unless `n` is 100 you can't pass it back to the function as it's expecting an array of size 100.

Comment: Using loops is more sensible than recursion, but the requirement is to use recursion. For each of the four scenarios, you need to know (a) how to detect when you’re done, (b) what to do in this recursive call, and (c) how to make a recursive call that gets you one step closer to finishing. Consider writing the iterative code (no recursion), and get that working. Then make a recursive version of the code with no loops, only iteration.

Comment: @WhozCraig edited it.

Comment: @Eugene Sh. I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: @crylikeacanary I mean, what this condition is corresponding to in terms of the description: `if (k<n || abs(k)<n)` ?

Comment: @EugeneSh. it checks if the absolute value of k is smaller than k so that is will print the first k numbers that fit the further description. I guess I could just write abs(k)<n but that doesn't really solve the main problem.

Comment: So if you have 100 items in the original array, the first call to `function` will create a `b` array with 99 items, then the next call will create a `b` array with 98 items, and so on. That's a lot of unnecessary wasted space, I would think.

Answer (score 0):

I found three issues with your code.

1) When I copied your code (converting to C# because that's what I work with), it threw an ArgumentOutOfRangeException for me here:

```
for (i=0; i<n; i++)
{
  b[i]=a[i+1]; <------
}
```

When `i` is 99, it tries to copy `a[100]` into `b[99]`, but there's no `a[100]`. You should change the `for` loop to this instead:

```
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++)
```

2) Your code is essentially treating `a` like a queue and popping the first number off (by copying all the others into a new array `b`), but instead of looking at that first number to determine whether or not to print it, you're skipping it and looking instead at the first item you just put into `b`:

```
if (k>0)
{
    if (b[0]>0) <------
    {
        printf("%d", b[0]); <-----
        k=k-1;
    }
}
```

You should change your comparisons (and `printf` lines) to look at `a[0]` instead of `b[0]`.

3) Whenever `k` is larger than `n`, then your entire logic block will get skipped (for example, I mistakenly set `k` to 34 instead of 3, and when I did, the `if` block reads `if (34 < 6 || abs(34) < 6)`, which is always false.